# add_column applies to a matrix

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a `2-by-2`  tibble, and use `add_column` to add a `2-by-2` matrix. I want to have a resulting `4-by-4` tibble, but it ends up with a `2-by-3` tibble.

Here is a sample code:

```
A <- tibble( x = c(-1,1), y = c(-2,2))

A <- A %>% add_column( z = matrix( rnorm(4), 2,2 )   )
```

and `dim(A)` returns  `2 3`.

So my question is how this resulting matrix can be `2-by-4`?

Comment: i dont understand these answers, why does `cbind(A, z = matrix(rnorm(4), 2))` not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try

```
> A %>% add_column(as_tibble(matrix(rnorm(4), 2, 2)))
# A tibble: 2 x 4
      x     y     V1     V2
  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1    -1    -2 -0.647 -0.982
2     1     2 -0.264 -1.25
```

---

If you want to add columns with names starting with `z`, we can use

```
A %>% add_column(setNames(as_tibble(matrix(rnorm(4), 2, 2)),paste0("z",1:2)))
```

or (thank akrun's comment)

```
A %>% add_column(as_tibble(matrix(rnorm(4), 2, 2, dimnames = list(NULL, c('z1', 'z2')))))
```

Answer (score 1):

We can flatten to regular columns from the `matrix` column 'z' with `do.call` and `data.frame` call

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
A %>%
    add_column( z = matrix( rnorm(4), 2,2 )   ) %>%
    do.call(data.frame, .) %>%
    as_tibble
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 2 x 4
#      x     y   z.1   z.2
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1    -1    -2 -1.41 -1.93
#2     1     2  1.80  1.01
```

---

Or another option is to split the `matrix` into a `list` with `asplit` and use `unnest_wider`

```
library(tidyr)
A %>% 
  add_column( z = matrix( rnorm(4), 2,2 )   ) %>%
  mutate(z = asplit(z, 2)) %>% 
  unnest_wider(c(z))
```